# How to solve circular import in django model?

Tags: python, django

I have created one apps in django: lecture

The code in lecture.models

```py
class SchoolDepartment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class Professor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    school_department = models.ForeignKey(SchoolDepartment)


class Lecture(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor)
    school_department = models.ForeignKey(SchoolDepartment)
```

When i run, this code raise error.

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'SchoolDepartment' from partially initialized module 'lecture.models' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have got to know, the error is because of the circular import.
So i change this code like this.

```py
class SchoolDepartment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class Professor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    school_department = models.ForeignKey('lecture.SchoolDepartment')


class Lecture(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor)
    school_department = models.ForeignKey('lecture.SchoolDepartment')
```

But still raise error.
And It's full traceback.

```sh
namsul_web | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
namsul_web | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
namsul_web | Traceback (most recent call last):
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
namsul_web |     self.run()
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 888, in run
namsul_web |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
namsul_web |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
namsul_web |     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
namsul_web |     raise _exception[1]
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
namsul_web |     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
namsul_web |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
namsul_web |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
namsul_web |     app_config.import_models()
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
namsul_web |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
namsul_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
namsul_web |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
namsul_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
namsul_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
namsul_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
namsul_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
namsul_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
namsul_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
namsul_web |   File "/opt/project/NamSul/account/models.py", line 4, in <module>
namsul_web |     from lecture.models import Lecture, Professor
namsul_web |   File "/opt/project/NamSul/lecture/models.py", line 4, in <module>
namsul_web |     from .managers import SchoolDepartmentManager
namsul_web |   File "/opt/project/NamSul/lecture/managers.py", line 2, in <module>
namsul_web |     from .models import SchoolDepartment, Professor
namsul_web | ImportError: cannot import name 'SchoolDepartment' from partially initialized module 'lecture.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/project/NamSul/lecture/models.py)
```

It's my INSTALLED_APPS in settings file

```py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'lecture.apps.LectureConfig',
    'board.apps.BoardConfig',
    'traffic.apps.TrafficConfig',
    'corona.apps.CoronaConfig',
]
...
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are these defined in separate `models.py`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, It's same `models.py`

Comment: and `lecture` is in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes.

Comment: I am not sure you are showing the relevant bits here. Can you show the full stacktrace

Comment: @progresshans: and there is no other app that imports `SchoolDepartment` that is loaded *after* the `lecture` module (so placed before `'lecture'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edit my post. I add full traceback and INSTALLED_APPS list

Comment: @progresshans; `account` imports models from `lecture`, but since `account` is placed *before* `lecture` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`, these are not loaded yet. You thus should swap the order, or work with string literals in the models of the `account` app.

Comment: May be removing this line from top of lecture.models will work "from .models import SchoolDepartment, Professor". You are sitting in lecture.models and trying to import models contained in it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Lecture's foreign key was omitted from the post(Now i edited). Professor's foreign key exists in lecture.

Comment: @progresshans:it does not matter if you *use* the models, you *import* these in the models of your `account` app...

Comment: @Amit It was this problem. I modified the code to use `self`.